# Using a projection from the elements instead of a comparator for sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator, projection

I searched for c++ analog for this (python):

```
sorted(vector, key=lambda x : my_function(x))
```

There is of course the construction:

```
std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return my_function(lhs) < my_function(rhs);
});
```

I just wondering if one-argument construction exists.

Comment: No. Algorithms is range based using iterators. But you can always do by yourself a version with one arg...

Comment: You may want the c++ 20 ranges. Before that it was all iterator pairs.

Answer (score 4):

Using ranges instead of iterator-pairs when you want will come with C++20.

Aside from that, a projection (in combination with a flag for reversing the order) is more concise where the job is straight-forward, like all sub-keys in the same order, and all sorted according to their "natural" ordering.
A comparator is not relentlessly optimised for that scenario, trading that ease for all-around optimal performance and easy implementation of more demanding and even outright weird orders.

Python's [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) only allows for a projection and optional reverse-flag.

[`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts elements, optionally according to a custom comparator. In principle, it could be extended to try using the passed function-object (if any) as a projection if it doesn't work as a comparator, feel free to propose it for standardisation.

Until and unless that happens, you can easily synthesise a comparison from a projection and an order-relation though:

```
template <class Projection, class Comparator = std::less<>>
struct use_projection {
    [[no_unique_address]] Projection p = Projection();
    [[no_unique_address]] Comparator c = Comparator();
    template <class... T>
    auto operator()(T&&... t) const
    noexcept(noexcept(c(p(std::forward<T>(t))...)))
    -> decltype(c(p(std::forward<T>(t))...))
    { return c(p(std::forward<T>(t))...); }
};

auto my_projection = [](auto&& x)->auto&& { return x.y; };
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), use_projection{my_projection});
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), use_projection{my_projection, std::greater()});
```

Adapting that idea for pre-C++17 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are asking if there is a sort function in the standard library that sorts by a given key rather than with a comparator.

There is nothing like this in the standard library. In Python, since objects are table-based -- since the fundamental notion of a struct or a record is ultimately implemented in the language as a mapping between string keys and values that may be functions -- it is possible to succinctly refer to a field as a string. In C++ this is not the case. If you have a something like

```
struct Foo {
    std::string name;
    int id;
};
```

the names of the fields,"name" and "id", are not known to the running program; they exist only as artifacts of the source code. So to do something like the Python key-based sort you would need to provide a function (or a callable object anyway) to extract the key value you want to use from each item.

Something like the following would work:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void sort_by_key(Iter from, Iter to, Func get_key) {
    std::sort(from, to, 
        [get_key](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
            return get_key(lhs) < get_key(rhs);
        }
    );
}

struct Foo {
    std::string name;
    int id;
};

...

std::vector<Foo> foobar{ {"quux", 10000}, {"mumble", 12}, {"frobnicate", 42} };
sort_by_key(foobar.begin(), foobar.end(), [](const Foo& foo) {return foo.name; });
```